# Conditionally assign values to DF column using np.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group some columns into a list inside a single column.
In case one of these columns contain NaN, the result column should be just NaN instead of the list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a.0':[11, 1.1], 'a.5':[12, 1.2], 'a.10':[13, pd.np.NaN]})
```

The result column of the DF should be as such:

```
    a.0   a.10   a.5   result
0 . 11.0  13.0   12.0  [11, 13, 12]
1 . 1.1   nan    1.2   nan
```

These 2 lines do the job:

```
df['result'] = df[['a.0','a.10','a.5']].values.tolist()
df['result'] = pd.np.where(df[['a.0','a.10','a.5']].isnull().any(axis=1), pd.np.nan, df['result'])
```

And I was wondering how to do it in one line. Help would be appreciated

Comment: why are you trying to store nested values in a dataframe? this is generally a bad idea.

Comment: what is `arr_cols`?

Comment: Your code gives me a `ValueError`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, tx, I fixed that

Comment: If your answer works, it's the best one.

Comment: @PaulH by nested you meant for the lists within a column?
This is formatting before converting to JSON

Comment: @HagaiIsraeli Your answer still does not work for me, on v0.21. Also, please see my answer with timings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `isnull` + `any` + `mask`/`where`

```
df['result'] = pd.Series(df.values.tolist()).mask(df.isnull().any(1))
```

Or,

```
df['result'] = pd.Series(df.values.tolist()).where(~df.isnull().any(1))
```

```
    a.0  a.10   a.5              result
0  11.0  13.0  12.0  [11.0, 13.0, 12.0]
1   1.1   NaN   1.2                 NaN
```

---

**Performance**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
# Wen's solution
%timeit df.apply(lambda x : pd.Series([x.tolist()]) if ~x.isnull().any() else np.nan,1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 37s per loop

# Anton vBR's solution
%timeit [np.nan if np.isnan(v).any() else list(v[1:]) for v in df.itertuples()]
1 loop, best of 3: 5.79 s per loop

# my answer
%timeit pd.Series(df.values.tolist()).mask(df.isnull().any(1))
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop
```

---

**Conclusions**

- `apply` is inefficient, more so than a loop. An `apply` call typically has many overheads associated with it. A pure python loop is generally faster.
- A vectorised approach such as `where`/`mask` will vectorize operations and offers improved performance over loopy solutions.

Comment: @AntonvBR Sorry, was in the process of timings, but it's been over a  minute and Wen's answer is still not done... :-(

Comment: I created my own small set with some random choice. His answer was clearly slow. :). Haha nice 1min 37 s.

Comment: If you can test my second way ?

Comment: @Wen It changes the dtype, so it may not be a valid answer. I can test it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That is ok  , No worry , I will remove it

Comment: @Wen `1 loop, best of 3: 8.45 s per loop`!

Answer (score 2):

**Update** With timings and large data-sets cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ answer is the best. List comprehensions always suffer here. I've updated my previous answer with timings.

You could use [itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and assign np.nan if any np.nan in row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a.0':np.random.choice(np.append(np.nan,np.arange(10)), 1000), 
                   'a.5':np.random.choice(10, 1000), 
                   'a.10':np.random.choice(10, 1000)})

# 3 solutions to solve the problem 
# Assign with df['results'] =
%timeit [np.nan if np.isnan(v).any() else list(v[1:]) for v in df.itertuples()]
%timeit pd.Series(df.values.tolist()).mask(df.isnull().any(1))
%timeit df.apply(lambda x : pd.Series([x.tolist()]) if ~x.isnull().any() else np.nan,1)
```

---

Timings:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 8.38 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 772 µs per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 214 ms per loop
```

Comment: @HagaiIsraeli Nothing I can think of with clear syntax.

Comment: @AntonvBR Take a look at my answer (for the clear syntax :-) )

Answer (score 2):

```
df['result']=df.apply(lambda x : pd.Series([x.tolist()]) if ~x.isnull().any() else np.nan,1)
df
Out[30]: 
    a.0  a.10   a.5              result
0  11.0  13.0  12.0  [11.0, 13.0, 12.0]
1   1.1   NaN   1.2                 NaN
```

Comment: Found a new way :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aha a nice way : -)